# Does anyone use Statistical Element Selection for matching integrated circuit components or is this a university exercise?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, integrated-circuit, matching, finfet

I have to fix the transistor mismatch on a finfet amplifier design.  I've seen lots of papers on Statistical Element Matching, all from universities, but haven't seen anything reported by companies actually selling products.

[https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~xinli/papers/2008_CICC_mismatch.pdf](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Exinli/papers/2008_CICC_mismatch.pdf)

Does anyone know if this method is real or just theoretical?  Are there circuit designs in production?

Comment: If your fab_supplied SDK does not provide matching guidelines, then contact the fab liason person.

Answer (score 0):

So the basic idea is to improve matching by selecting the best-matching devices and using them. It seems like a basic type of digital trimming that could be done during wafer probe. Many parts go through a trimming procedure for various parameters. It used to be done by shaving metal off of resistors using a laser, I think, but more commonly in my experience it's done by blowing on-chip fuses. That would work fine for this type of trim, assuming there is an accurate way to determine which devices are best matched at probe.

I'd be surprised if it isn't commonly used in many analog designs. However, it would usually be considered a proprietary implementation detail, not something that would be advertised. Circuit manufacturers are not in the habit of broadcasting exactly how they make their circuits, since it mainly helps their competitors and it can open them up to patent lawsuits.

Comment: I didn't think about the patent infringement issue.  My real concern is about temperature drift after the matching components are selected.  I think the general idea makes sense, but that's only part of the story (i.e. temp drift, aging, etc.) hence my question. thanks.

Comment: Regarding temp drift and aging, it is very likely that identical cells that are near each other on a chip will have identical characteristics, assuming there are unused dummy cells surrounding them as is normally done, and assuming they undergo the same stress (e.g., not running one at a higher average voltage than the other).

Answer (score 0):

Statistical optimization methods are fairly common, though it is usually a Monte Carlo approach that is used. The paper you cite appears to rely on detailed process statistics for transistors, which may not be available to most customers. Unless your design team is tightly coupled to the fab line you may have to rely on best/worst/nominal transistor models.